# ListView onItemClick not working in the Activity

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

When i am using this in the activity which has the ListView, it didn't work.

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            ong arg3) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UsersListActivity.this,
                UserActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

after searching for a solution i ended up doing it in the `getView()` of the **Adapter**

```
convertView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            ong arg3) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity,
                UserActivity.class);
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

This works. But why such strange behavior. Why isn't it working the way it should.

Thank You

Comment: Are you using Custom Adapter.?

Comment: Yeah. I am using **CustomAdapter** for almost all the ListViews in my project. There are about 10-12. But i never faced this error. one thing that might interest you is: **I use the same parent and same list_item for 3 ListViews, but with different adapters** that shouldn't cause any problem right?

Comment: I have tried to provide some explanation of this unexpected behaviour in my answer below. Let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new
>   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {`

Here you have used `View` of `Adapter View`, which is the parent class of your `Custom Adapter`. that's why it is not working. Instead you should have used the `View` of `Custom Adapter`.

`getView()` function here helps you to convert the View of Parent `Adpater View` to the `Custom Adapter` View.

So you use either of the two options,

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

or

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

Both of the options might work.

Comment: This looks like it. But why was it working everywhere else until now? In fact out of the 3 similar ListViews with same Layout and same ListView items, 1 works fine and the other 2 doesn't

Comment: I dont think, it should be so. There might be something diffrerent in the list view that was working. Because if you are using Custom Adapter, you have to use the view of the same adapter.

Comment: The only difference is the 1 which works doesn't have any clickable children in the ListViewItem. The other 2 have a Button whose onClickListener is implemented in the getView().

Comment: That's it. You got the explanation. If you need to use the onClickListener, you need to use the view of custom adapter.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: Anytime, infact thanks to you. I havent thought about it before, but your post let me understand it deeply.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [on a blog](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/):

There will be case that your custom list item doesn’t respond when you click…so what’s the reason and what’s the solution?

Here several problems and solutions:

### 1. Scenario: list item layout contains CheckBox

Problem: OnItemClickListener doesn’t respond.

Reason: CheckBox is also having its own click listener by default to change its state, and it overrides the container ListView.

Solution: remove focus on CheckBox by setting these attributes to `false`

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

### 2. Scenario: random

Problem: OnItemClickListener just doesn’t repond any at all!!!!

Reason: No idea..

Solution: in code, just set OnItemClickListener before setting Adapter. It works randomly @@!

### 3. Scenario: list item contains ImageButton

Problem: OnItemClickListener just doesn’t repond any at all!!!!

Reason: No idea!!!

Solution: in code, set ImageButton focus to `false`

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
button.setFocusable(false);
```

### 4. Scenario: list item contain TextView

Problem: OnItemClickListener just doesn’t repond.

Reason: I think you have set this attribute to TextView: `android:inputType=”textMultiLine”`

Solution: just remove that attribute, using `android:minLines/android:maxLines` instead.

### 5. Scenario: list item contain a TextView that is linked to website URL or whatever “mailto:” things

Problem: OnItemClickListener just doesn’t repond.

Reason: the TextView overrides focus of list item.

Solution: just remove attribute `android:autoLink` on TextView.

Answer (score 1):

it will work

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
       Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, UserActivity.class);
       mActivity.startActivity(intent);
       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom AdapterView you need to refer to that AdapterView. I think if you referred to the superclasses adapterview and when you call `setAdapter()` then your code block of `new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` will not execute.

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            ong arg3) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UsersListActivity.this,
                UserActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But this is what i have been using all the time. Never caused such an issue.

Answer (score -1):

try this line use in Activity class.

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

this line use only Adapter in Activity class this is not working. i think not sure

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```