# onItemClick using multiple ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

i have a layout with multiple ListView that work perfect and i can't capture any click on any item.

The items on all the ListViews has the same type of information and i intend to use one Adapter to show that information on another layout.

I've searched and i found 2 good ways to do it, the first way do nothing when i click on any item, and the second don't let me start the destination activity and i don't know what to do more...

The layout that contains the ListView's:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="50dp" >
            </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="50dp" >
            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
        ....
        ....
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my first code:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Object o = arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
    Intent i = new Intent(MyClass .this, ViewMyClass.class);        
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

When i click on any item it does nothing and i don't know why..

My secon code:

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list1);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        Object o = arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
        Intent i = new Intent(MyClass .this, ViewMyClass.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    });
}
```

Usinc this code, when i click on a item of the first ListView don't start the activity ViewMyClass and also don't know why

I've also tryed to do this and nothing:

[AdapterView.OnItemClickListener with more ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855444/adapterview-onitemclicklistener-with-more-listview)

[ListView onItemClick not working in the Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020423/listview-onitemclick-not-working-in-the-activity)

I've alse tryed to do this, but if i change extends Activity with ListFragment almost all my code that works turns to errors...

[Android programming - onitemclicklistener for multiple listviews doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308192/android-programming-onitemclicklistener-for-multiple-listviews-doesnt-work)

I will keep searching and trying because i know it has to be a solution to this without changing all the code, but if anyone can help...

Thank you all.

Comment: Remove `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` from second code and check.

Comment: Try not to bind the same adapter object to multiple listsview, rather just create the two objects of adapter and bind one - one to each listview, data source maybe same. First Try this and let me know, than i will let you explain why this is require.

Comment: Try this `private class Myclass implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.listview1:            
            break;
        case R.id.listview2:
            break;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Hi to all, i tryed to remove AdapterView.OnClickListener and leave only the second code leaving:

public class MyClass extends Activity{
and

lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
Object o = arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
Intent i = new Intent(MyClass.this, ViewMyClass.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});

and nothing

Comment: responding to jitain sharma, i'm sorry but i don't know what you mean with create two adapters

Comment: responding to Aniruddha, thanks, but i think that your code is for start diferent intents for every listView and i only have 1 intent to call, elements of all lists go to the same layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these two ways,this will help you...

1. From Your Second Code ,just remove `implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` from class

   `public class MyClass extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

and run the code.

2. Replace your code by this::

   ```
   public class MyClass extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
           super.onCreate(icicle);
           setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);   

           lv1 = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list1);

           lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
       }

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
           Object o = arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
           Intent i = new Intent(MyClass .this, ViewMyClass.class);
           startActivity(i);
       }

   }
   ```